# Maintaining Language cookie when navigating from one site to other site

Tags: c#, sitecore

I Have one site lets say www.abc.com/ and other site lets say www.abc.com/blog/
here I want to maintain language cookie when request is like www.abc.com/pt-br,
then cookie will be have pt-br value if then request goes for www.abc.com/blog/en this will maintain cookie of en,and i go back to the first site it should show me the cookie of pt-br and not cookie of en.I want to maintain custom cookie for this which store the language value for this.so how should I achieve this can anyone help me into this?

Comment: You could store the language setting in session, this is passed around for that user throughout the domain.

Comment: Do you mean application? `www.abc.com/` is the same site as `www.abc.com/blog/` and as such cookies set to work for the root of that site will be visible to both. If you want to do it for different sites like `www.abc.com/` and `www.xyz.com` then that's very different.

Comment: Are both sites part of the same Sitecore instance? If so, are they both from the same site definition, or separate site definitions?

Comment: both the sites are in same site defination.

Answer (score 2):

if www.abc.com and www.abc.com/blog are different websites in sitecore.config then sitecore stores different language cookies(website#lang). You don't not need to do anything.

For making www.abc.com/blog as different site you should add site node in 'sites' section like below:

```
<site name="AbcBlog" virtualFolder="/blog" physicalFolder="/blog" rootPath="/sitecore/content/Home/Blog" />
```

Then your required functionality will be achieved by sitecore out of the box functionality

Comment: I don't want to use multiple sites.this is same site such as www.abc.com/ and for blog www.abc.com/blog.
scenario: 1) when I am in www.abc.com/en then cookie of lang is set for en, then I go to www.abc.com/pt-br then lang cookie is to pt-br.2)when I will navigate to www.abc.com/pt-br/blogs then lang cookie will be pt-br and I set custom cookie to en.there is logo on blog site which is navigate to en by default ,so when i click on that logo it should redirect to pt-br and not on en so how should i handle this?

Comment: Why you are setting custom cookie to en on your point2? Why logo is set to en? Like you said language cookie set to pt-br so logo URL should be pt-br try checking how are getting URL for logo?

Comment: there is requirement  that logo should be default in en and when we are in blog page of any language that logo always in default language i.e.en but when we are in other language and when I click on that logo i don't want to redirect to en ,i want to redirect it on that specific language.can you please help me into this or provide any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

As Dheeraj mentioned, this is mostly out of the box functionality for Sitecore.

It would be easiest to keep the blog and the main site as separate `<site>` definitions in web.config so they can both maintain their own cookie. You can do this even if both are part of the same content branch e.g.

```
<site name="MainSite"
      virtualFolder="/"
      physicalFolder="/"
      rootPath="sitecore/content/AbcSite" />
<site name="Blog"
      virtualFolder="/blog"
      physicalFolder="/blog"
      rootPath="sitecore/content/AbcSite" />
```

Provided both sites have a language cookie set, you could render links from one to the other with something like

```
var otherSiteLanguage = //retrieve language from cookie
var options = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
options.Language = otherSiteLanguage;
Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
```

Obviously the above only works in cases when you **know** the link is going to be from one site to the other, so could be useful for a site logo link etc, but would not work for a link within a rich text field.

If the blog and the main site are handled by the same `<site>` definition and you cannot change that, then the language stored in the cookie would persist for both sites, so changing the language for the main site would change the language for the blog and vice versa. In this case, you might be best off coming up with some sort of language fallback scheme where you switch to an alternative language if the one held in the cookie is not supported by the current site. You could do this within the httpRequestBegin pipeline by creating an override version of the LanguageResolver processor (`Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest, Sitecore.Kernel`).

Comment: I don't want to  use multiple sites.there is same url such as www.abc.com/and for blog www.abc.com/blog.

Comment: scenario: 1) when I am in www.abc.com/en then cookie of lang is set for en, then I go to www.abc.com/pt-br then lang cookie is to pt-br.2)when I will navigate to www.abc.com/pt-br/blogs then lang cookie will be pt-br and I set custom cookie  to en.there is logo on blog site which is navigate to en by default ,so when i click on that logo it should redirect to pt-br and not on en so how should i handle this?